# linear transformation of a basis where $T(v_1) = w_1, ..., T(v_n) = w_n$

Tags: linear-transformations

On p.796 of Anton's Elementary Linear Algebra, there is a question.
Prove: If $(v_1, v_2, ...,v_n)$ is a basis for V  and $(w_1,w_2, ...w_n)$ are vectors in W, not necessarily distinct, then
there exists a linear transformation $T:V \rightarrow W$ such that
$T(v_1) = w_1, T(v_2) = w_2, ..., T(v_n) = w_n$

I know that the set $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ is linearly independent and spans V because it is a basis.  The set $(w_1, ..., w_n)$ could be linearly dependent.
I let $v=(c_1v_1 +...+c_nv_n)$ be an arbitrary vector in $V$.
Then the transformation of $v$ is $T(c_1v_1 +...+c_nv_n)=w_i$.
Let $w_i=c_1w_1+...+c_nw_n$ so $(w_1,...,w_n)$ spans $W$.
To show that $(w_1, ...., w_n)$ is linearly independent,
let $c_1w_1 +...+c_nw_n =0$ only have the trivial solution of $c_1, ...,c_n =0$ meaning $(w_1, ...,w_n)$ are distinct vectors.

Edit: 
Now show that $T$ is closed under addition and scalar multiplication.

Let $u=k_1v_1+...+k_nv_n$ be an arbitrary vector in $V$.

$T(u+v)=(k_1w_1+...+k_nw_n)+(c_1w_1+...+c_nw_n)=T(u) + T(v)$

Let $d$ be a scalar where $T(du)=dk_1w_1+...+dk_nw_n=d(k_1w_1+...+k_nw_n)=dT(u)$.

Edit 2:

$T(v_i) = w_i$ where v_i is in the basis of $V$ and $w_i$ is in $W$.
Let $v_j$ be a vector in basis of $V$.
$T(v_i+v_j)=w_i + w_j=T(v_i) + T(v_j)$
Let k be a scalar (real number).
$T(kv_i)=kw_i=kT(v_i)$

The transformation is linear because it satisfies the requirements for closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: the list $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ doesnt necessarily span $W$, that is, you are assuming that $T(V)=W$ but all that you knows is that $T(V)\subset W$. And observe that $$T(c_1v_1+\ldots+c_nv_n)=c_1w_1+c_2w_2+\ldots+c_nw_n$$ if $T$ is linear.

Comment: @Masacroso if I use the word "let..." can I assume it spans $W$?

Comment: no, you cant assume that a random list of vectors span the whole space. Anyway the text is not clear, you are mixing different exercises in the same question?

Comment: @Masacroso No, it's just one question. Why can't I assume that set $(w_1,...,w_n)$ spans W?

Comment: because it is not stated, the exercise doesnt says that $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ spans $W$ or is a basis of $W$, just that $w_1,\ldots,w_n$ is a list of vectors in $W$. To prove that $T$ is linear you only need to prove that it have linear properties, that is: $$T(\lambda v+\mu w)=\lambda Tv+\mu Tw,\quad \forall v,w\in V,\forall\lambda,\mu\in\Bbb F$$ where $\Bbb F$ is the field of $V$, and that the domain of $T$ is $V$ and $T(V)\subset W$.

Comment: I wanted to say: $T$ could be linear, that is, you must prove that exists some linear function $T:V\to W$ where the system of equations defined by $Tv_j=w_j$ holds.

Comment: @Masacroso.  I'm a bit lost.  Someone told me to that the $T(v_j)$ is equal to the transformation of the basis vectors of $V$.  And then to find the matrix $A$ that is the transition matrix of the bases $B$ and $B'$ going from $V \rightarrow W$ so that I can find the basis vectors of $W$.  Is this the only way to solve this?

Comment: the transformation of a basis of $V$ to a list of vectors that spans $W$ can be defined by a linear map $T$ if two conditions holds: $\dim W\le \dim V$ and $T$ is surjective.

Comment: @Masacroso, so aside from the notation that I'm not 100% clear on, basically show closure under addition and scalar multiplication?

Comment: I let $B = (e_1,...e_n)$ be the standard basis for V.  Then $(v_1, ..., v_n)$ can be expressed as a linear combination of vectors in $B$.  So $T(v) = T(c_1e_1+c2_e2+...+c_ne_n)=T(c_1e_1)+...+T(c_ne_n)$ The result is some vector $w$ in $W$.  Take an arbitrary vector $u$ in $V$ and using the same equation would give another vector in $W$.  Therefore, $T(v+u) = T(c_1e_1+...c_ne_n+k_1e_1+...+k_ne_n) = T(c_1e_1)+...+T(c_ne_n)+T(k_1e_1)+...+T(k_ne_n)=T(v)+T(u)$.

Comment: For scalar multiplication, take an arbitrary vector $v_j=kv$ where $k$ is a real number.  $T(v_j)=T(kv)=T(k(c_1e_1+...+c_ne_n))=T(kc_1e_1)+...+T(kc_ne_n)=kc_1T(e1)+...+kc_nT(e_n)=w_j$  $w_j$ is in $W$ and is unique since we know that the basis vectors $(e_1,...e_n)$ in $V$ are unique.  So this transformation is linear, one-to-one and onto.

Comment: My last comment is not displaying properly.

Answer (score 2):

since the $\bar v_i$ form a basis, any vector $\bar u$ may be written in a unique way as:
$$
\bar u=\sum_{i=1}^n u_i\bar v_i
$$
define
$$
T\bar u = \sum_{i=1}^n u_i\bar w_i
$$
and show $T$ has the required properties

Comment: Well noted.  I am going to try to show closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

Comment: Just learned from a student at ENS I met that it is wrong to assume that T is one-to-one.  He is using different terminology but sounds like I have to work with the matrix of T relative to the bases B and B'.

Comment: Yes, $T$ need not be 1-1. and it need not be surjective. the essential points are (1) a linear map is defined completely by the values it takes on the elements of a basis for the domain (2) those values can be chosen with complete freedom.